# Fetch case sensitive nature of directory

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs

Windows 10 April 2018 update added [opt-in feature](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10) to have per directory case-sensitive pathnames.

[This](http://othermedia.info/?p=6510) page tells me that I can query this info using [NtQueryInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile).

Is there any non-kernel mode driver (for ex. GetFileAttributesExW or FindFirstFileExW) function that can fetch the same information ?

We have some restrictions at our workplace for not using Nt or Zw APIs.

Comment: `NtQueryInformationFile` is user mode routine too and you can call it from user mode. possible to `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` will be added `FileCaseSensitiveInfo` - need look in latest sdk

Comment: Unclear, what restrictions you really have. `NtQueryInformationFile` can be called from user mode. Can you not use the `Nt` family of functions or can you not call native API functions from kernel mode?

Comment: You will have to fix the badly thought out rules which prevent you from solving the problem.